# How can I make target depend on specific filename?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gnu-make, automake

I'm trying to use `Makefile` to manage few tasks around my project (for example packaging it for distribution). However I cannot find a way to depend on specific file name instead of some auto-magic. See example:

```
+   $ cat Makefile
dist: ctl
        echo "package it here"

+   $ tree
.
├── ctl
└── Makefile

0 directories, 2 files

+   $ make
echo "package it here"
package it here
```

As you can see, this works fine. But it stops working the moment when I create files `ctl.h` and `ctl.c`:

```
+   $ touch ctl.{h,c}

+   $ make
cc     ctl.c   -o ctl
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.2.1/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: ctl] Error 1

+   $ tree
.
├── ctl.c
├── ctl.h
└── Makefile

0 directories, 3 files
```

My assumption is that `make` is trying to be smart and considers `ctl` to be program compiled from `ctl.c`. Which is not such a case. How can I suppress this behaviour?

Comment: Define an explicit rule for building `ctl` so it won't use the built-in rules.

Comment: What is the reason to have `dist` depend on `ctl`? If you want to run the commands for `dist` only if the file `ctl` is modified, target `dist` must create a file `dist`. If `dist` is a phony target, it doesn't make sense to have dependencies except from other phony targets which should be executed before `dist`, e.g. `dist: all` if you want to automatically `make all` before running the `dist` commands.

Comment: Just to guarantee that `ctl` exists before `dist` starts running

Comment: How is this related to the `automake` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "implicit rule" to create `ctl` from `ctl.c` is only used when there's no explicitly stated rule to create `ctl`.  For instance, if `ctl` should be compiled from the source files `ctlcmd.c` and `common.c`, then write:

```
ctl: ctlcmd.o common.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

(The `.o` files will be created from the `.c` files using another implicit rule.)

If `ctl` does not need to be re-created at all (e.g. it's a hand-written script), then you can write a dummy rule for it, like this:

```
# `ctl` is a hand-written file, don't try to recreate it from anything
ctl:
        touch ctl
```

You should also write some rules to tell Make what it *should* be doing with `ctl.c`.

Comment: `ctl` is hand written script in my case, but I was getting `+   $ make
make: 'ctl' is up to date.
`..

Comment: Yes, because `ctl`, being hand-written, has no dependencies, so it is always up to date.  Is it a problem that make prints that?

Comment: No, it's not; I've just put it as first rule in the makefile and wondered why `make` no longer does anything except that message. When called `make dist` it works correctly, thank you :)

Comment: Generally the first rule in the makefile should be named `all`, and it should have no commands of its own, but it should depend on everything that you want to build normally.  That way just typing `make` does the Right Thing.

Answer (score 2):

*Make* comes with a bunch of pattern rules, which it tries quite hard to use.
One of them says how to create executable `foo` out of `foo.c`. This is what is happening to you.

Personally I intensely dislike these rules and usually disable them using the `-R` parameter.

```
$ ls
ctl  ctl.c  Makefile

$ make -R
echo "package it here"
package it here

$ make
cc     ctl.c   -o ctl
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ctl] Error 1
```

Now, it's not nice to require your users to have to use a certain parameter.
One way forward is to simply cancel all the implicit rules.
You can destroy the list of file extensions that *make* considers as candidates for application of a pattern rule.
A simple `SUFFIXES:` will do.

```
$ ls
ctl  ctl.c  Makefile

$ cat Makefile
.SUFFIXES:
dist: ctl
       echo "package it here"

$ make
echo "package it here"
package it here
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally `make` assumes all targets will create a file of the same name. If no dependency is specified as for `ctl` in your example, `make` tries to guess the dependency, for example if you have a file `ctl.c` it assumes it can build `ctl` from `ctl.c` by using standard rules.

Assuming your targets `dist` and `ctl` should never be build as files you can declare them as phony targets by adding a line

```
.PHONY: dist ctl
```

see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html